# Why am I getting a segfault here?

Tags: c

Code to split data into a training / test subsets is below.  Note that data_points is one long vector of size items*attr, and data_labels is a vector of size items.

```
int split_data(int items, int attr, double *data_points, int *data_labels, double **split_train_points, int **split_train_labels, double **split_test_points, int **split_test_labels)
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int i, j;
  double temp0, temp1;
  double sorter[items][2];

  *split_train_points = malloc(floor(SPLIT_PROP*items * attr) * sizeof(double));
  *split_train_labels = malloc(floor(SPLIT_PROP*items       ) * sizeof(int));

  *split_test_points  = malloc(ceil((1-SPLIT_PROP)*items * attr) * sizeof(double));
  *split_test_labels  = malloc(ceil((1-SPLIT_PROP)*items       ) * sizeof(int));

  // create a 2d array with element number in one column and a random number in the other
  for (i = 0; i < items; i++) {
      sorter[i][0] = i;
      sorter[i][1] = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
  }

  // sort by the random number column
  for (i = items-1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      if (sorter[j-1][1] > sorter[j][1]) {
        temp0 = sorter[j-1][0];
        temp1 = sorter[j-1][1];

        sorter[j-1][0] = sorter[j][0];
        sorter[j-1][1] = sorter[j][1];

        sorter[j][0] = temp0;
        sorter[j][1] = temp1;
      }
    }
  }

  int cutoff = floor(SPLIT_PROP*items);
  int element = 0;
  // now we have a bunch of indices in a random order.  we select the first 70% to store into our split_train datasets
  for (i = 0; i < cutoff; i++) {
    element = (int)sorter[i][0];
    *split_train_labels[i] = data_labels[element];
    printf("success!\n");
    for (j = 0; j < attr; j++) {
      printf("j: %d, data_points_element: %d\n",j,attr*element+j);

      //SEGFAULT OCCURS HERE WHEN J=4 EVERY TIME EVEN AS ELEMENT VALUE CHANGES DUE TO RANDOMNESS
      *split_train_points[attr*i+j] = data_points[attr*element+j];
      printf("j out! %d\n",j);
    }
  }


  for (i = cutoff; i < items; i++) {
    *split_train_labels[i - cutoff] = data_labels[(int)sorter[i][0]];

    for (j = 0; j < attr; j++) {
      *split_train_points[attr*(i-cutoff)+j] = data_points[attr*(int)sorter[i][0]+j];
    }
  }  

  return 0;
}
```

As noted in the code, SEGFAULT occurs at the same line, at j=4, even though "element" is a random number.

Comment: If you run in a debugger, and so know where the error is, it should be easy to tell what the indexes for those arrays are and to check if they are out of bounds or not.

Comment: What's a *training/test subset*?

Comment: Your code is not self-contained (no `main()`). Not only you should be executing it in a debugger, but you are asking others to help you without allowing them to execute it in a debugger.

Comment: Is this line working? printf("j: %d, data_points_element: %d\n",j,attr*element+j);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess it's because the expression `*split_train_labels[i]` doesn't mean what you think it means. For the compiler that is the same as `*(split_train_labels[i])`, but you probably mean `(*split_train_labels)[i]`. You have this problem in multiple places.

Array indexing has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than pointer dereference.

Comment: Gah, stupid mistake.  Thank you :)